# Django Rest Framework why is ModelSerializer creating objects with all null fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Package. I am trying to save new instances and update existing instances of it in my database by using a ModelSerializer from Django Rest Framework. I want to make a GET request of all Packages from the API server, and save them as new objects or update existing ones in my database.

I am successfully creating new objects of Package in my database, however all fields are empty.

view.py

```
def pckgs(request):
    result = {}
    message = ""
    save_message = ""

    endpoint = "removed for stack overflow"

    response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=auth, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:  # SUCCESS
        result = response.json()
        s = PackageSerializer(data=result, many=True)
        if s.is_valid():
            s.save()
        else:
            save_message = s.errors
    else:
        message = response.status_code + " there was an error"

    context = {'result': result, 'message': message, 'response_url': response.url, 'save_message': save_message}
    return render(request, 'core/pckgs-active.html', context)
```

serializers.py

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Package.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.label = validated_data.get('label', instance.label)
        instance.package_type = validated_data.get('package_type', instance.package_type)
    # ---snip--- there are 32 fields
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

I receive no errors from `s.errors`. On my first try of this method, I did get a few errors that certain fields couldn't be null. I temporarily allowed null values in these fields, and the errors disappeared. Is something causing the serializer to want to save a null value for every field?

The only fields that have values are the ones with a `choices=` attribute and a `default=` set.

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried walking through the process in the shell, which provides a clearer view of what's going on:

```
>>> for item in result:
...     s = PackageSerializer(data=item)
...     if s.is_valid():
...             print(s.validated_data)
...             print(s.data)
... 
OrderedDict()
{'label': None, 'source_harvest_names': None, 'room_id': None, 'room_name': 
None, 'quantity': None, 'unit_of_measure': None, 'unit_of_measure_abbrev': 
None, 'patient_license_num': None, 'product_id': None, 'product_name': None, 
'product_category_name': None, 'packaged_date': None, 'lab_testing_state_date': 
None, 'production_batch_number': None, 'remediation_date': None, 
'received_from_manifest_number': None, 'received_from_facility_license_number': 
None, 'received_from_facility_name': None, 'received_date_time': None, 
'archived_date': None, 'finished_date': None}
```

Why am I losing all the values in this process? When I run

```
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

I get each dict with correct key:value pairs having values.

Likewise the following statement also still prints correct values:

```
for item in result:
    s = PackageSerializer(data=item)
    print(s)
```

Comment: does `response` contains the data? it can be just empty so your fields are empty as well

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Yes, I get the response I was expecting from the GET request. If I print out result it prints a list containing 12 ordered dicts, which are what I'm trying to create the model objects from.

Comment: It nows seems like the problem has to do with s.is_valid() returning an empty OrderedDict, but I can't figure out how that's happening

Comment: It show that the `data` you have provided to serializer has `None` values as well, so serializer just  removes them from `validated_data`. Can't find anything suspicious in your code, are you sure you are passing dict with data to serializer? it shoulnd't mutate `data` anyway....

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Running it in the debugger shows that the dict I'm passing to the serializer has the correct data: `s = PackageSerializer(data=item) s: PackageSerializer(data={'Id': 33101, 'Label': 1234ABCD5678EFGH9123', 'PackageType': 'Product', --snip--}` The fields aren't set to None until validated_data is returned.

Comment: Wow,  I am lost now. What version of DRF are you using? Can you give me some sort of minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

The answer was obvious and therefore a little harder to catch. I simply had a mismatch between the fields in the Package model and the Keys in the JSON dictionary being fed into the ModelSerializer.

For instance, `label` in model and `'Label'` in JSON, `package_type` in model and `'PackageType'` in JSON.

In hindsight it's obvious. How would the serializer know in which fields to place the values?

`is_valid()` was returning `None` on every field because it was getting valid data as an input but didn't know where to put it.

In hindsight I also shot myself in the foot as far as debugging goes by temporarily allowing certain required fields to be null with `null=True` and `blank=True`. This allowed validation to complete successfully on required fields when in reality it wasn't getting the appropriate data.

Answer (score -1):

I think your view are incorrect

what is this:

```
response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=auth, params=params)
```

instead, you should use this code:

```
response = request.data
```

but if you don't have problem with generics module. use this module please

```
class MyCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    queryset = Package.objects.all()

class MyRetrieveUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
```